# Code after Promise.all doesn't get executed

Tags: node.js, promise, request, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl websites and create their sitemaps. I've found a library which extracts all the hrefs in a link which have the same domain with main domain.

```
const scrape_links_and_return_next = (links)=>{
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
    // This function maps each link, then crawls every href in that link
    let next_links = links.map((result_link,idx)=>{
      return limit(() => find_unique_links(result_link));
    })
    // After all the scraping jobs are complete do below for every scraping job
    let response = await Promise.all(next_links)
    console.log(response)
    // Create an empty array
    let resulted_next_links = []
    // Flatten the resulting array
    response.forEach((el,idx)=>{
      if(el){
        el.forEach((e,i)=>{
          resulted_next_links.push(e)
        })
      }
    })
    // Make it a hash set in case of any duplicates
    resulted_next_links = [...new Set(resulted_next_links)]
    console.log(resulted_next_links)
    return resolve(resulted_next_links)
  })
}
```

Here find_unique_links works just fine, it returns all the links in a page that aren't saved just yet. But somehow the code after Promise.all doesn't get executed and script just terminates. I don't know why but this behaviour changes based on different websites. Sometimes on the first batch, it works fine but in the second batch it does the same thing.

Comment: What does `limit(...)` do?

Comment: Ah, it's the p-limit package, limits the number of concurrent promises. Behaviour of the code is same without is as well.